# Strange keyboard behavior in authentication dialog's "reveal password" feature when using Windows Remote Desktop Connection to talk to server

Tags: remote-desktop, gotomypc

I am attached to my PC at work using GoToMyPC. From that work PC I'm trying to use Remote Desktop Connection to reach a Windows server on the LAN there.   My password to that server, which has worked for the past several weeks, is being rejected.

When I click on the eyeball icon in the authentication dialog in order to reveal the password, the pound-sign `#` is rendered there as a `3`. The same thing happens with any character created with the SHIFT key. A `%` when revealed in that manner is a `5`.

[image: Remote Desktop Reveal Hidden]

Is that how the "reveal hidden" feature of the Windows Authentication dialog always works? I've never actually used it before. FWIW, when I open Notepad on the work PC, shifted characters are being rendered properly.

Comment: Not a solution therefore not an answer either, just a possibly temporary workaround: Can you copy the (correct) password written on Notepad and paste it where you need it?

Comment: As a side question... does the RDP client not prompt for your credentials (NLA) _before_ making the actual connection?

Answer (score 0):

Rendering problems of that kind are quite unlikely; it's much more likely to be the simpler explanation that `3` and `5` is what was actually *input* to the password box – that's why the password is being rejected.

For example, it could be that the combination of GoToMyPC and RDP somehow became unable to deal with modifiers, i.e. the RDP client simply ignores <kbd>Shift</kbd> if it originated from GoToMyPC service. (I don't know why it would, but it certainly wouldn't be the first nor even 10th modifiers-related problem I had to deal with.)

Answer (score 0):

In the GoToMyPC menu bar click on *Tools > Preferences...*.
Tick the option "Pass Windows keys to host computer".

If this doesn't help, press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key a few times to see
if the key now behaves correctly.

Comment: `Pass windows keys on to host computer` was already enabled.  I've hit SHIFT multiple times with no change. My tests with Notepad on the host computer showed that SHIFT+3 was being transmitted correctly as `#` , SHIFT+4 as `$`, and so forth.

Comment: It seems that the problem is with RDP, meaning that the keyboard on the remote server is different from yours. Try on the remote computer you RDP into to use regedit to go to key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout` and create a new DWORD value named `IgnoreRemoteKeyboardLayout` and set it to `1`.

Comment: thanks for that suggestion. On the road for several days and will try it upon return!